# How can I output minicart block?

Tags: magento2, blocks

I am making changes to Luma theme. I want to move the minicart icon (`module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`) to a different location. `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('magento_checkout/sidebar'); ?>` doesn't seem to work. Do I need to create a module for this? I created a theme by extending Luma and I do all of the changes in `app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/*`

I come from Magento 1 and Magento 2 is really new for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply solved using XML. For example, I move minicart to left sidebar.

**app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="minicart" destination="div.sidebar.main" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget flush cache after modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Though Evgeny Levinsky ans will work but if you dont wish to make new theme then you can also do the same things using custom module

first create a custom module using this link https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

and then create a `default.xml` file at below location and add the following lines of code

```
<root>\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="minicart" destination="div.sidebar.main" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```